# Does the Decorator pattern improve performance?

Tags: php, design-patterns, uml, decorator

I firmly believe that the Decorator pattern really helps when maintaining your code, but does that help to improve performance overall in the web application? Because you have to create an instance of a class and then use it, but without it you just create links in the normal way. Just to refresh you mind, here is a code example:

```
<?php
   class decorateEmail implements decoratorInterface {
       public function decorate($item) {
           $return = '<a href="mailto:' . $item . '">' . $item . '</a>';
           return $return;
       }
   }
?>
```

And here is a UML diagram; I hope it helps more:

[image]

**EDIT:**
If the answer is no, can we infer that all design patterns are not helpful and that large scale web apps like Facebook, Digg, etc. don't use them?

Comment: Well, object instantiation + method call is certainly slower than no instantiation and no method call. Significantly so? Probably not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The *intent* of the decorator pattern is *not* to improve performance; it is to add behavior to an existing object.

Design patterns, when used judiciously, are useful to better control the design and evolution of a code base. Performance is just *one* concern of good software design and architecture; other concerns are e.g. maintainability, security and extensibility.

Design patterns are useful in large scale software development; but also take a look at *design principles*, like the [SOLID principles](http://butunclebob.com/ArticleS.UncleBob.PrinciplesOfOod).

Comment: In which way design patterns helps improving security? I know that it helps in maintainability, but not security!

Comment: The proxy design pattern, for example, can be used to control access to an object.